# object doesnt support this prpoperty or method

Tags: arrays, object, vb6

i have an object called bankBr of type BankBranch that im trying to fill in an array called list branch . but im getting an error : "`object doesnt support this prpoperty or method`"

```
    While Er = 0
      Dim bankBr As New bankBranch
      bankBr.SetBranchName BankTable.Fields("Name")
      bankBr.SetBranchID BankTable.Fields("ID")
      listBranch(i) = bankBr
      BrCount = BrCount + 1
      i = i + 1
      BankTable.ReadRow i, Er

    Wend
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't indicate which line was causing the error, but my guess it is this one:

```
listBranch(i) = bankBr
```

Try this instead:

```
Set listBranch(i) = bankBr
```

`bankBr` is an Object, and you need to use the `Set` keyword when assigning an object.  Otherwise, VB invokes the default property on the object which, if not present, would throw an error as you've described.